# Loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async contexts

Tags: python, discord, bots

I get an error message that seems to be coming from `discord_client.loop.create_task(background_task())`:

> loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async contexts. Consider using either an asynchronous main function and passing it to asyncio.run or using asynchronous initialisation hooks such as Client.setup_hook

Creation:

```
discord_client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

async def background_task():
    global message
    await discord_client.wait_until_ready()
    discord_channel = discord_client.get_channel(config["discord_channel"])
    while True:
        if message != []:
            await discord_channel.send(message[0])
            message.pop(0)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

discord_client.loop.create_task(background_task())
```

Launching:

```
asyncio.run(discord_client.run(config["discord_bot_token"]))
asyncio.run(client.run_until_disconnected())
```

I've done this and the bot starts, but it doesn't trigger any code after `await discord_client.start(config["discord_bot_token"])`:

```
async def main():
    print("Starting Bot")
    await discord_client.start(config["discord_bot_token"])
    print("Bot Started")
    await background_task()
```

How can I solve this properly?

Answer (score 0):

your on the right track. [asyncio.create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) is just what you need for this. `create_task` will let you run an async method in the background *without* blocking execution which is your main issue here.

Lets see how this translates to your code.

```py
import asyncio

import discord

discord_client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

async def background_task():
    while True:
        print("I'm a background task!")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def main():
    print("Starting Bot")
    asyncio.create_task(background_task)

    await discord_client.start(config["discord_bot_token"])

asyncio.run(main())
```

This code will run your bot while also executing the background task in the background. Hope this helps!